# Scraping Wikipedia Subcategories (Pages) with Multiple Depths?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, web-crawler, wikipedia

If you open the `computer science category` in wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Computer_science), it displays a total of `19` subcategories (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Computer_science). Now, for all these `19` subcategories, if I want to `extract` only the page names (the titles of pages). For example Pages in category `Computer science` has `45` pages which is displayed as `bullets` just below the wikipedia subcategories list. Now for all the other associated subcategories, for example the `Areas of computer science` is a subcategory with `3` pages (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Areas_of_computer_science). But, again it has 17 sub-categories (i.e. depth 1, considering the traversal, i.e. depth = 1 means, we are 1 deep). Again, `algorithm and data structures` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Algorithms_and_data_structures) having `5` pages, and `artificial intelligence` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Artificial_intelligence) having `333` pages with some additional `categories` and `subcategories` spanned in multiple pages (see Pages in category "Artificial intelligence") with 37 categories and 333 pages, like this the list goes on more deeper. We are now in depth 2. What I need is to extract all the pages (titles) for the traversal with depth 1 and depth 2. Does there exist any algorithm to achieve the same?

For Example: the subcategory area of computer science is again having some (17) subcategories with a total number of pages 5+333+127+79+216+315+37+47+95+37+246+103+21+2+55+113+94 pages considering all the (17) subcategories. This is depth 2 because, I toggled twice the list. Similarly, same thing needs to be incorporated for the rest 18 subcategories (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Computer_science) with a depth of 2 for the base root Computer science?

Does there exist any way to achieve this? Displaying and extracting that many number of pages is difficult because it will be huge. Thus, maximum threshold of 10,000 pages would be absolutely okay.

Does there exist any way to do this? Any small help is deeply appreciated!

Comment: to get started, have a look in the dev-tools that come with your browser.  e.g. chrome has a "network" tab that shows the queries going through as you expand each section.  you can see xml responses coming back which should help you figure out what endpoints to hit.  otherwise, wikipedia provides (large) data dumps that would allow you to get this yourself rather than crawl their site, and would be good to use depending on how deep you want to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tool called PetScan hosted by Wikimedia labs. You can easily type the category title, then select the depth you want to reach, and then it's done!. https://petscan.wmflabs.org/

Also, see how it works https://meta.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/PetScan/en

Comment: Interesting. Sure I will give a try!